# How to convert one struct to another in Go when one includes another?

Tags: go, struct

I would like to know if there is easy way to convert from one struct to another in Go when one struct includes the other.

For example

```
type Type1 struct {
  Field1 int
  Field2 string
}

type Type2 struct {
  Field1 int
}
```

I know that it can be handled like this

```
var a Type1{10, "A"}
var b Type2
b.Field1 = a.Field1
```

but if there are many fields, I will have to write numerous assignments. Is there any other way to handle it without multiple assignments?

In a word, is there anything like `b = _.omit(a, 'Field2')` in javascript?

Comment: Consider make `Type 2` embedded in `Type 1` if it is not against the design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, no. You can freely convert between *identical types* only.

You can get various levels of solutions to this type of problem:

- writing the assignments out yourself (likely the best performance)
- using reflection to copy from one to the other based on field names
- something quick-and-dirty like marshalling one type to JSON then unmarshalling to the other type (which is basically using reflection under the hood with a plaintext middleman, so it's even less efficient, but can be done with little work on your part)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't encode/decode into JSON because it already has tags for json for other purpose. Could you elaborate more about reflection?

Comment: @emil here's an example using the `reflect` package: https://play.golang.org/p/JkZ5Hi_Xyxw. It's just an illustration of how you can do it with reflection and it omits proper value validity checking, using it as is I do not recommend.